# Parse Author Style Sheet in timeline

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

So, according to [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/constructing-the-object-model?hl=en) from April 2014 (by Ilya Grigorik),

> the timeline doesn’t show a separate `Parse CSS` entry

but I guess this has changed since then, as there now seems to be a separate event for this, named `Parse Author Style Sheet` (`Parse Stylesheet` in Canary/Chrome 46)

Was the `Parse Author Style Sheet`/`Parse Stylesheet` event separated from the `Recalculate Style` event? What exactly does each of these two events now capture?